# Geting Error "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path" in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Function MasterDirectoryScanner(ByVal DirectroyInfos As DirectoryInfo, ByVal filter As String) As List(Of UInt64)
    Dim FileInformation As New List(Of UInt64)

    Dim file_size As UInt64 = 0
    Dim file_count As Integer = 0

   **For Each fi In DirectroyInfos.GetFiles(filter)**
        Try
            file_count = file_count + 1
            file_size = CULng(file_size + fi.Length)
            FilesToDelete.Add(fi.FullName)
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            'There's really no pretty way to handle this exception
        Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
            'There's really no pretty way to handle this exception
        End Try
    Next

    For Each di As DirectoryInfo In DirectroyInfos.GetDirectories
        MasterDirectoryScanner(di, filter)
    Next

    FileInformation.Add(CULng(file_count))
    FileInformation.Add(file_size)

    Return FileInformation
End Function
```

I am getting error in this line "For Each fi In DirectroyInfos.GetFiles(filter)"

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
Message=Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern)
   at ACleaner.UniducksCleaner.MasterDirectoryScanner(DirectoryInfo DirectroyInfos, String filter) in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\Classes\UniducksCleaner.vb:line 272
   at ACleaner.UniducksCleaner.MasterDirectoryScanner(DirectoryInfo DirectroyInfos, String filter) in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\Classes\UniducksCleaner.vb:line 285
   at ACleaner.UniducksCleaner.MasterScanner(String FileRegOrDirectory, ListView lvw, DirectoryInfoA di, FileInfoA fi, RegistryInfoA ri) in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\Classes\UniducksCleaner.vb:line 324
   at ACleaner.UniducksCleaner.scan_Directories(ListView lvw) in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\Classes\UniducksCleaner.vb:line 237
   at ACleaner.UniducksCleaner.Scan(ListView lvw) in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\Classes\UniducksCleaner.vb:line 218
   at ACleaner.frmMain.Initiate() in C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\Developer Kit\ACleaner\frmMain.vb:line 533
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException:

Comment: What is the question?, do you not understand "Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied"

Comment: Did you try a different folder? If it works against a different folder, it is probably your file system (permissions, locks etc.).

Comment: The problem is that you don't have access rights to that folder for the user running your process. Read the actual words in the error message - they almost always have meaning. In this case, `UnauthorizedAccess` in the name of the exception tells you the problem, and "Access to the path" would be the folder. Put the two together: "Unauthorized access to the folder" is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

The Try-Catch does not handle the error because the error occurs outside the try-catch block.

You can do one or both of these to prevent the crash:

1. Include the initial `for` statement in the try-catch block, and
2. Check the permissions of `DirectroyInfos`. Here's how:

   If ((File.GetAttributes(foldername) And FileAttributes.System) = FileAttributes.System) then ...

Comment: I just want to skip these folder without throwing error those are protected.

Comment: I added a line on how to do that in (2) of my answer. If you have problems with something other than system folders, you can add other attributes to the test. You can check this before the For statement.